# RMarkdown ioslides - cannot change font-family

Tags: css, r, rstudio, r-markdown, ioslides

I am trying to change the font family for the whole my presentation as unfortunately default font makes a mess with Polish specific letters (ą, ę, etc.).

I tried the following approaches:

1. Change the header of presentation

---

```
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation: 
    font-family: 'Arial'
```

---

2. Add css file with the following code:

---

```
pre {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: red;
}
```

---

I know that 2. should change only output from code. Unfortunately, I haven't found how to make changes to the whole document via css (it's my first time with it).

Unfortunately, none of the above solutions worked. Funny is that the second solution changed the color but didn't change the font.

Can anyone help?

Kuba

Comment: To have the font apply to the whole document, you could probably do something like `html { font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important; }`. This may be a bit too broad, however.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, but when I added !important to the solution 2 it changed my text with code. So the question would be, how to find out what are the elements of css that needs to be changed  in order to apply font change for all text elements that are not from R (the ones that you have to type manually)

Comment: Or the other way around: what elements do you need to exclude? See `:not()` CSS selector.

Comment: Probably only pre. HOw do I use this :not selector?

Comment: In my evironment the code chunks stay the same even if you use `body { font-family: Times New Roman; }`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer looks like :not is working for now, if I find any further problems with will keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer but hopefully, others can benefit from this.

In your CSS file, you can refer to the whole presentation using the following:

```
slides > slide {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

The `slides > slide` selector ensures that your declarations are applied to the whole presentation. This should work perfectly fine.

Let me know if you're still having problems.